# Linq to Entities performance within ASP.NET Development Server

Tags: linq-to-entities, asp.net-development-serv

I've been evaluating linq to entities and linq to SQL for a project.

Obviously each has its own advantages and disadvantages which have been discussed plenty of times here.  However, One thing I am seeing with L2E is kind of odd.

Using L2S, when using the ASP.NET Development Server, the performance is a little slower for my web service calls.  I'm looking at 300ms vs. 250 ms.

However, when using L2E, when using ASP.NET Dev Server, the performance is awful.  I'm talking 1,250 ms vs. 220 ms.

I know I should probably just use local IIS for development, but I'm curious if anyone else has seen this, or knows what is causing it.